# Ruby/Rails: trying to invent an inherited resource gem. Class instance variable in mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class-instance-variables

I want to DRY my views and controllers from a lot of similar code. I want to do it by myself in educational purpose, I know about the InheritedResourse gem.
So far I wrote:

```
class Admin::ResourcesController < Admin::AdminBaseController
    before_filter :get_model_name

    def index
        result = @model.all #Resource.all
        instance_variable_set "@#{@@collection_resource_name}", result # @resources = result
        result # return it duo it can be used with super
    end

    def show
        result = @model.find(params[:id])
        instance_variable_set "@#{@@instance_resource_name}", result
        result
    end


    protected

    @@collection_resource_name = 'resources'
    @@instance_resource_name = 'resource'

    def self.set_resource_name(hash)
        @@instance_resource_name = hash[:instance_resource_name]
        @@collection_resource_name = hash[:collection_resource_name]
    end

    private

    def get_model_name
        @model = controller_name.classify.constantize # Resource
    end
end
```

Only two actions, but you got the idea: abstract any model to a 'resource', set a list of model fields (or get it dynamicaly) and that's it.

First of all, I think instead of @@instance_resource_name (class variable), I need a class instance variable. I'm right?

... but, it is not a main question. I think that it's cool when this kind of code is wrapped in mixin. Because in my example it is Admin::ResourceController, but I can also have a User::ResourceController or just something another.
Ok, I wrapped it in a mixin. For usability, I want to call something like `actions only: [:index, :show]` in controller in section, where I put `before_filter`, for example.
How this section of code is called? Class instance?
Ok, the example:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module ScaffoldResources
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do

        def hello
            self.class.action_list
        end
    end

    module ClassMethods
        @action_list = [:new, :show, :index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :create]
        attr_accessor :actions_list
        def actions(*params)
            @actions_list = params
        end
    end
end
```

For testing, I create this small controller:

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::ResourcesController
    include ScaffoldResources
    @actions_list = 'hard set'
    actions 'some','actions','i think'

    def show
        render json: hello
    end
end
```

So, when I call hello method (it do only `self.class.action_list`) I want to see anything. I set class instance variable in mixin and in class – hardcode and through method defined in mixin. But it's nil!
I think you got the idea, what I'm trying to achieve. How it can be achieved?